# NLP conversion between parts of speech and pertainyms?

Tags: morphology, computational-linguistics, nlp, parts-of-speech, nltk

I would like to write a program that can automatically group e.g. 'happiness', 'happily', 'happy' into 'happy':

1. What do I need to read to get a handle on this subject? What is it called? What is the state-of-the-art?
2. Are there any out of the box tools I can use for this?
3. WordNet claims to include some cross-POS links, and its home page states that "Relational adjectives ("pertainyms") point to the nouns they are derived from (criminal-crime).". How do I access these using, for example, Python's NLTK?

I've read some posts referring to 'nounification' (I guess I want to 'adjectify') but can't find any solid answers.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I guess you're looking for a **lemmatizer**. There are many free or Free implementations.

Comment: Hmm - nltks wordnet lemmatizer does not merge 'happily' and 'happiness' - can two different parts of speech be considered lemmas of one another?

Comment: Are you trying to do [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)? [There's an nltk package for that](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html). Basically, it removes all modifiers from a word so you just have the stem (or root) word left.

Comment: @prash: I would say this is one of the several differences between a **lemmatizer** and a **stemmer**. The former shouldn't remove derivational prefixes whereas the latter generally do.

Comment: @hippietrail: sure, but I almost never recommend a stemmer: it seems so useless unless the user has very special circumstances :)

Comment: @prash: Me too. I suppose stemming is good for searching by inexact term. Stack Exchange does just that in fact. But for actual NLP you generally want the more expensive lemmatization operation. To normalize `happiness`, `happily`, `happy` like the OP wants is a stemming operation. I wonder if it's what the OP really wants or needs though?

Comment: OP here. I have thousands of single word responses some of which are emotions. Unfortunately, respondents have generated e.g. happiness, happy, happily when they mean to say 'happy' and joy, joyfully, joyously when they mean 'joy', etc. I want to normalize so that in the first case the three words get rolled into the e.g. adjective form, 'happy' and in the second case 'joyful'. If I use wordnet's lemmatizer from python's nltk, this does not seem to combine happiness, happy, and happily - they remain distinct. If I stem instead, do I run the risk of combining e.g. happy and hapless into hap?

Comment: @user3279453: You definitely want stemming rather than lemmatizing. The stemmers I briefly looked at focussed on being fast and efficient at the cost of precision so there will definitely be some false negatives and some false positives. The stem returned might not even be a correct word in its own right. But it sounds like you do have a legit case for NLP quality stemming and there may be something out there that handles inflection and derivation at linguistic quality.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [your comment](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/nlp-conversion-between-parts-of-speech-and-pertainyms#comment21945_9071), you seem to be looking for positive words with the intent of performing [sentiment analysis](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html) (generally lists are divided into positive, negative, and neutral). Here are some lists to get started with ([a Google search](http://bit.ly/1rzfRnK) will turn up plenty more):

- [Hu and Liu, KDD, 2004 (~6800 words)](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/opinion-lexicon-English.rar)
- [Breen, *Twitter Sentiment Analysis Tutorial*, 2011](https://github.com/jeffreybreen/twitter-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-201107/tree/master/data/opinion-lexicon-English)
- [Davies, *Sentiment Analysis Word List*](http://alexdavies.net/twitter-sentiment-analysis/)
- [University of Pittsburgh MPQA](http://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/) ([see also paper](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~wiebe/pubs/papers/emnlp05polarity.pdf))
- [There are also several APIs you use for sentiment analysis](http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-20-sentiment-analysis-apis/)

As a side note, word lists are only marginally helpful in detecting/classifying sentiment. It will capture the low-hanging fruit, but not more complicated or ambiguous phrases such as "watch the movie" (which is a positive movie review, but a negative book review).

As far as extracting pertainyms goes, any good POS-tagger will allow you to identify the predicted direct object of a verb and whatnot, but as you are likely aware, this is fraught with its own complications.